# PySide QGLBuffer allocate input data

Tags: python, qt, opengl, pyside

I'm trying to run PySide version of OpenGL Core Profile Qt demo - [How_to_use_OpenGL_Core_Profile_with_Qt](http://qt-project.org/wiki/How_to_use_OpenGL_Core_Profile_with_Qt).

It uses QGLBuffer.allocate() method (C++ code)

```
float points[] = { -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                    0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
m_vertexBuffer.allocate( points, 3 * 4 * sizeof( float ) );
```

Pythonic way will be:

```
points = [-0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 1.0,
           0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 1.0,
           0.0,  0.5, 0.0, 1.0]
m_vertexBuffer.allocate(points)
```

But when I run this code I get following error

```
TypeError: 'PySide.QtOpenGL.QGLBuffer.allocate' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide.QtOpenGL.QGLBuffer.allocate(list)
Supported signatures:
  PySide.QtOpenGL.QGLBuffer.allocate(void, int = -1)
  PySide.QtOpenGL.QGLBuffer.allocate(int)
```

I found [unit test](http://pyside.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.0.1-1/qglbuffer__test_8py_source.html) that is used for this functionality - it uses QByteArray.

```
data = QByteArray("12345")
b.allocate(data)
```

But I don't understand how to convert Python list to QByteArray or use allocate with list. Or is it bug in PySide wrapper function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I found solution. We should use python modules like struct or array. For example:

```
from array import *

points = [0.5, 1, -0.5]
data = array('f', points)
# data.tostring() - returns packed data with size of len(data.tostring())
```